# How to convert 'unescaped string' to string in Java

Tags: java, string, ascii

Question above.

And by 'unescaped' I mean `"Hello \\n \\\"World\\\""`.

```
String myString = "Hello \\n \\\"World\\\"";
System.out.println("Before : \n");
System.out.println(myString);
String myConverted = escape(myString);
System.out.println("After : \n");
System.out.println(myConverted);
```

Output:

```
Before :

Hello \n \"World\"
After :

Hello
 "World"
```

So I would be converting it to `"Hello \n \"World\""`.

I want it to escape the characters.

Is there a function to do this? `escape` is only an example.

Comment: P.S, I dont know the term to unescaped strings, and I dont want to use generic replace methods, I want to escape any supposing escape characters.

Comment: There isn't, and, you've got your terms mixed up. Your input string is 'escaped', and that method should be called 'unescape'. The concept of a 'backslash-n' is called an 'escape'; hence, turning a string containing a newline into a string containing backslash + n is 'escaping' it, and the reverse is 'unescaping' it. Note that this sounds like an X/Y problem. For example, you used regexes to parse a string out of some JSON. The real solution is to use a JSON library, not to try to write your own unescaper. There is no such method in core java.

Comment: @rzwitserloot ok, the  java suceks, I give up on using it...

Comment: since Java 15: `String myConverted = myString.translateEscapes();` - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()) (which can be searched)

Comment: Ah, hey, now - nice find, @user85421 - so there is!

Comment: *"the java suceks, I give up on using it."* -- somehow I think Java will not suffer because of this.

Comment: @dilettante I dont really mean it, im sure java is a really great language, and so are others too! Im just, having a hard time wrapping my mind around java.

Comment: Technically, those are _un-escaped_, _un-escaped_ _[escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too much `\`s. To make new line you need `\n`, to make `"` will do `\"`.
Place 3 of `\\\"` and you get one `\` escaped before escaped `"`
Therefre if you generate this data it need some adjust. If you recieving it this way, unfortunately you have to make some rules of processing. Hovever since 15 java there is easy way:

```
    String myString = "Hello \\n \\\"World\\\"";
    System.out.println("Before : \n");
    String s = myString.translateEscapes();
    System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

Comment: No need for `String::replace`, just use [`String::translateEscapes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()).

Comment: You helped the development of the programming language Luca! Thank you!